# Inferring the type of (f .) in Haskell

Tags: type-inference, haskell

If we have the following in Haskell:

```
f x y = x + y
:type f
f :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

then GHC would report `Num a1 => (a2 -> a1) -> a2 -> a1 -> a1` as the type for `(f .)`.
Would you please explain me the steps through which GHC comes to such conclusion?

Comment: Note: Haskell specific question is off-topic here.

Comment: First, `(.)` is an infix binary operator `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`. Next, `(f .)` is the same operator, but partially applied with the first argument. So, `(f .) :: (a -> b) -> a -> c`

Comment: You can see that `f` is taken to provide something of type `b -> c` for the first argument of `(.)`. But since you already define previously that `f :: Num a => a -> a -> a`. So GHC put bracket as `f :: Num a => a -> (a -> a)` to match the expected type `b -> c`

Comment: @Apwit Thank you for your clear answer. But for my question being off-topic I just used Haskell as an expressing platform, and my question was generally about inferring the type in general. Thanks again.